# Sidebar won't sit right - shifted to bottom right

Tags: html

Just doing a bit of coding and everything was fine and now suddenly when I change something not related to the sidebar at all the sidebar decides to move, I can't seem tow work out a reason why it would though.

The code is quite long so I'll just post a link to the page:

[Here](http://www.thisdigicore.com/htmlcheck)

Can someone help me explain why it suddenly moved to a weird position? Might be because I plonked a program on the page and didn't format it very well, any helps greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Seem's I changed the order of the divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The floating sidebar div has to go **before** the content div in your HTML Code.

Comment: Sorry tried to accept it straight away, had to wait 8 minutes then work took voer again :)